# Automate sending multiple PDFs from google drive folder

Tags: email-attachments

I have the following google app scrip to generate PDFs from a google sheet. The date in the sheet goes to a google doc template and then the PDFs are generated in a folder. I need to automate sending the PDF files as attachment in a mail via Gmail to be sent to each person according to his email.
My code:

```
 function generateStudentReportPDFs() {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the data range for the sheet
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  // Get the values from the sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Loop through the data and generate a PDF for each row
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var firstName = row[0];
    var lastName = row[1];
    var email = row[2];
    var grade = row[3];
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var dictation = row[5];
    var participation = row[6];
    var monthlyTest = row[7];
    var total = row[8];
    var remarks = row[9];
    
    // Make a copy of the template document
    var docId = DriveApp.getFileById("1WUPCODmqOfk0nRGnkmGiPjzDH3ibGUzVfZfZMuDDwBQ").makeCopy("Report").getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    
    // Replace the placeholders in the document with the appropriate values
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{First}}", firstName);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Last}}", lastName);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Email}}", email);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Grade}}", grade);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Today}}", today);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Dictation}}", dictation);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Participation}}", participation);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Monthly Test}}", monthlyTest);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Total}}", total);
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{Remarks}}", remarks);
    
    doc.saveAndClose()
    
    // Save the document as a PDF
    var pdf = doc.getAs("application/pdf");
    
    // Save the PDF to Google Drive
    var folderName = "Reports";
    
    // Check if the folder exists, if not create it
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      folder.createFile(pdf).setName(firstName + " " + lastName +" "+ today + ".pdf");
    } else {
      var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
      folder.createFile(pdf).setName(firstName + " " + lastName + " "+ today + ".pdf");
    }
     // Send the PDF as an email attachment
    }
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "", ""{
      attachments: [pdf]
    });
      // Delete the temporary document
    DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```

but it sends only the last row in the sheet. Please, help.
Thanks